# Feasibility of Continent Spanning Trees

Tags: evolution, flora

I have a world smaller than Earth (radius= 3,900 Km) with the same gravity and it is largely covered in interconnected continents. I also have a species of tree that can create a clonal forest of itself much like the Quaking Aspen. This tree also has the ability to redistribute water and nutrients to parts of itself that need it.

Edit:These continents are very fragmented and largely flat allowing for rain to make its way farther inland from the ocean.

Example: "Pando"
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVJLd.jpg)
Wikipedia Article: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pando_(tree)

Is it feasible for this tree to cover all of the planet's land area even in areas it shouldn't (Deserts) if so, is its nutrient redistribution ability plausible?

Comment: this is going to depend a lot on the the continent, if the continent is mostly mountain and desert the answer will be No. size and climate matter. Covering Asia will be different than covering Australia or South America.

Comment: @John I added a little bit of clarification to my post!

Comment: This is at least semi-plausible. Clonal colonies such as Pando are know to maintain "sacrificial clones" which act as concentrators for toxic compounds, allowing the clonal colony to survive in conditions that would otherwise kill them, which implicitly requires a mechanism for transferring water and nutrients throughout the colony.

Comment: I actually disagree that this question is a duplicate. The other question involves a waterworld where the worldtree forms the sole solid surface & sum total of non-marine habitats. This world seems to be a more ordinary terrestrial planet with a single tree colony spanning a continent.

Comment: It wasn't exactly a duplicate but it seemed to answer the basics of my question!

Comment: This sounds like the baobab trees from the little prince.  Baobab or aspen might work.  But if there were other competing trees they would get out competed.  In real lofe aspen i think is one of the first to move in to an area in the succession of the forest.  They eventually make way for other species pines and firs etc

Comment: I am voting to reipen because interlocking trees are not necessarily clonal forrests, and vice-versa.

Comment: I wish I could vote to reopen this...  It deserves a better answer than the one it is marked as a duplicate of...