# Is there any upper limit on the size a plant can reach?

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, hard-science

Is there any innate limitation (like the square-cube law for animals) that restricts the size which a plant can grow to?  Is it simply a matter of having sufficient nutrients and time?

I've been considering including a planet where most of the native flora consists of a single superorganism, similar to a clonal colony, in one of my games, and I'm wondering how realistic this is.

Comment: Here is something:  https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/117517/feasibility-of-continent-spanning-trees  but it was closed because of this prior something:  https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/54293/planetary-surface-of-trees

Comment: Thanks- that question didn't show up when I was checking for duplicates.

Comment: Are you asking about vertical height or lateral extent (area covered by a single plant)? If lateral extent, then [Tasmania horizontal scrub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anodopetalum) might be a model.